# Ubuntu 22.04 Postfix apt upgrade missing maps files post upgrade

Tags: apt, postfix

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, Postfix, APT

Security updates are enabled, and APT is applying updates to postfix.
However, post-upgrade postfix is left in a non-functional state.
We get these errors in the logs:

```
postfix/proxymap[4090947]: warning: pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-domain-aliases.cf is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: pgsql
```

As I understand it, postfix removes the "maps" files before the upgrade and is supposed to put them back in place at the end. However, the maps files appear to not get re-added post upgrade.

Mail ceases to flow because critical maps files are not available.
And worse, service monitoring apps like Naemon/OMD think everything is fine, because the SMTP process is still accepting messages, but no actual mail flows.

A simple restart of the postfix process fixes it, but I need to figure out why APT is going so wrong doing the update.

The last two postfix updates (Jan 23 and today) both caused this issue.
And YES, Postgres is installed and is working fine.
Yes, I've checked the logs and the `apt update` is exactly when the problem started.
Google and other searches don't seem to find many/any results similar.

Comment: What got upgraded?

Comment: The migration script would be somewhere like `/var/lib/dpkg/info/postfix.postinst`. If that script neglects your config, then you should file a bug